# Faster way to match PDF's to SQL Records

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a C# web application that matches PDF files to records in an Azure SQL server database.  Part of the PDF file name includes the record ID.  I don't have all the PDFs for all the records as they come in via SFTP.  Currently, I make a list of all the file names, then loop through that list, pull out the record ID, find the matching record in the database and update the record.  For 2k records this takes about 10 minutes to process.  I was wondering if there was a faster or better optimized way to handle this?

```
string us_retail_directory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DFCUSretailloanDirectoryGet"];
string us_post_directory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DFCUSLoanDirectoryPost"];
MoveFileRecords counts = new MoveFileRecords();

DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(us_retail_directory);
FileInfo[] Files = directory.GetFiles("*.pdf");
foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
{
    string fileSplit = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name);

    string[] strings = fileSplit.Split('_');
    //string loanCode = strings[1];
    string loanCode = strings[1].Remove(strings[1].Length - 3);

    using (LoanFileEntities db = new LoanFileEntities())
    {
        IQueryable<dfc_LoanRecords> query = db.Set<dfc_LoanRecords>();
        dfc_LoanRecords record = query.FirstOrDefault(f => f.loan_code_string == loanCode && f.region == "US");
        if (record != null)
        {
            record.loan_file = file.Name;
            record.found_date = DateTime.Now;
            db.SaveChanges();

            if (!File.Exists(us_post_directory + file.Name))
            { File.Move(file.FullName, us_post_directory + file.Name); }
            else
            {
                string now = string.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd_Hmm}", DateTime.Now);
                File.Move(file.FullName, us_post_directory + "(dup" + now + ")" + file.Name);
            }

            counts.usRetailMove++;
            counts.recordCount++;
        }
        else
        {
            counts.usRetailSkip++;
            counts.recordCount++;
        }
    }
}
return counts;
```

Comment: What *specifically* takes 10 minutes? Did you actually profile your code to see where you spend time waiting?

Comment: Can't you move `db.SaveChanges()` to outside the loop? I assume that this will speed up the process quite significantly, as all records are updated together.

Comment: Write a [CLR Stored Procedure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx), it's silly to pull all the pdf's toward a client application. Keep the data on the database server and do your thing there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each database lookup has some latency whereas the actual amount of data will propably not be your biggest issue.

Therefore try to batch the requests by loading multiple records at once (even if you won't use all of the fetched records [an appropriate overhead has to be determined by testing]).
You can do this in sql with a list contains (when having a set of ids) or prefetching records according to some other appropriate mechanism (e.g. by date).

Then try to match on the prefetched records and batch the insert operations.

**EDIT**
In your case you may query multiple records at once using a Contains expression on loan_code_string.